# How to find out how many records have been loaded into table per load timestamp

Tags: sql, timestamp

I need to create log table (group data from COR and put information to log table about how many
records have been loaded into COR table per load timestamp). I've already tried add a timestamp column to table but after add a records it shows NULL value.

Thanks in Regards

Answer (score 0):

Even If I use this statement:

```
CREATE TABLE ExampleTable (PriKey int PRIMARY KEY, created_at timestamp);
```

and add test value:

```
INSERT INTO ExampleTable (PriKey, created_at ) Values (1, DEFAULT);
```

My result on created_at column is rowversion data type...
Anyone helps?